# .NET Core 2.2 Shared Cookie causes Bad Request error when logging in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have 2 applications that share cookies between them. This is the configuration in both the startup.cs:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.Name = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(CONST.CookieName);
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
    options.Cookie.Path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(CONST.CookiePath);
    options.Cookie.Domain = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(CONST.CookieDomain);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(CONST.CookieExpiryTimeSpanInMinutes)));

    options.LoginPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(CONST.LoginPath);
    options.AccessDeniedPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(CONST.AccessDeniedPath);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

The problem now is that if I load App A and App B together, login into App A then click login on App B, I get a Bad Request error. I tried to debug App B to check why it was getting this error and I discovered that when I am logged in to App A and try to login on App B, the Application doesn't know that I have already been authenticated.

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

The line above is always false.

Is there a way to prevent this issue? Or is there a way to check if a cookie has already been set?

EDIT:

I have set the Data Protection Key for all the apps:

```
var ds = new DirectoryInfo("PathTOKey");
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(ds)
    .SetApplicationName("DPName");
```

EDIT:

Cookie Options in Startup.cs

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = false;
});
var ds = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(UCCASGlobals.CentralApplicationSettings), "KeyRing"));
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(ds)
    .SetApplicationName(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(UCCASGlobals.DataProtectionApplicationName));

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.Name = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(UCCASGlobals.CookieName);
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
    options.Cookie.Path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(UCCASGlobals.CookiePath);
    options.Cookie.Domain = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(UCCASGlobals.CookieDomain);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(UCCASGlobals.CookieExpiryTimeSpanInMinutes)));

    options.LoginPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(UCCASGlobals.LoginPath);
    options.AccessDeniedPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(UCCASGlobals.AccessDeniedPath);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

Comment: What happens when you load the AppA and later AppB (instead of opening together)? Does the AppB loads properly?

Comment: Hi @user1672994, when I load AppA and then AppB, it loads properly. AppB redirects to the home page without any issue.

Comment: AppB will not know if AppA is already authenticated if they share the cookies if opened together. You can redirect to login page if `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` in AppB (and AppA) is **false** so that browser tries to login *silently* and set the required cookies and header to app to work.

Comment: I tried to debug AppB after AppA has logged in but I get pushed to the home page immediately and none of my login code was reached. However, I get the Bad Request error. I placed the User.identity.IsAuthenticated in my Login Page and the Submit Login function so if they are hit, it will definitely trigger. The issue is that the code isn't getting hit at all.

Comment: Can you please check what has triggered at bad request? You can put the break points in Startup where you are adding the Authentication logic. Is clicking on login page on AppB is a API request or redirect request?

Comment: Also, can you please put all the breakpoints in Global Exception Handler to know what is the actual exception. Also, you can put the breakpoints in other pre request methods like filters e.t.c

Comment: I removed all filters so there shouldn't be at any. Also, what do you mean put a breakpoint in the Global Exception Handler? Do you mean wrap my code in a try/catch function? The clicking on login page is not an api request. its a form submit to redirect.

Comment: You can write the Global exception handler in asp.net mvc. You will find various article to achieve it on internet. Incorporate that to know where the request if converted to BadRequest.

Comment: I tested it and it looks like the Authorize Attribute is setting the BadRequest error. Is there a way to debug it?

Comment: @user1672994 is there an example of a custom authorize attribute? I have tried searching for it but I can't seem to find any. I am currently using the original authorize attribute.

Comment: Can you please post your how are you adding Cookie Authentication in the app. Link to attach event in the cookie validation - [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Hi @user1672994 I have added it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have configured data protection in both of application and data protection keys and the app name must be the same in two Apps .

Configures the data protection system to persist keys to the specified directory. This path may be on the local machine or may point to a UNC share.

```
services.AddDataProtection()
         .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\Keys"))
         .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
          options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
        });
```

You could check the cookies value by cookie name in the request

```
var cookie=Request.Cookies["Cookie Name"];
```

Reference :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: I have already done that. The problem is that cookies can only be loaded on a new http request. What I'm doing now is loading the 2 different web apps at the same time, logging in to one and then logging in to another one. That is the cause of my Bad Request error because the second app detects that there is already a cookie too late.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to share the cookie. The cookie is encrypted, so both apps must be set up to encrypt/decrypt the same. This is done via data protection providers, and requires persisting the keyring to a common location both apps can access and ensuring that both use the same application name (which controls the segregation of keys).

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem("{PATH TO COMMON KEY RING FOLDER}")
    .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");
```

This is all in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: My bad, I didnt add this. I actually share the cookies already. The issue is that in when I am logged in to App A, I just need to refresh the page in App B and I will be redirected to App B's homepage. However, when I am logged in to App A and I click the login button in App B, I  get the error as stated above.

Comment: I need a way to check if cookies have been set when I click the login button. The User.Identity.IsAuthenticated doesn't do it/

Answer (score 0):

I seem not be able to reproduce the `BadRequest` you're getting when logging in both applications at the same time. I even manually created the demo in my github: https://github.com/davidliang2008/DL.ShareCookiesApps

- Both web apps are backed with one Identity system
- Both web apps are configured to be protected the entire site with `.RequireAuthenticatedUser()` policy

When I start both applications from Visual Studio, from the screenshot below, you can tell

- Logging into App B right after logging into App A won't throw an error
- Logging out one of the Apps will automatically logout the other implicitly (clicking the home page will ask the user to authenticate again)
- Logging in one of the Apps will automatically log in the other implicitly (clicking the home page will let the user in)

[image]

The only problem I'm encountering is when I put both sites together in one browser (I'm using latest Chrome), they will crash together. They're running fine when they're in separate browser instance.