# How to set breakpoint on [Authorize] Attribute

Tags: c#, attributes, asp.net-core-mvc, breakpoints, bad-request

Is it possible to set a breakpoint on the [Authorize] Atrribute in my class? It has been causing Bad Request errors and I was wondering what inside the [Authorize] Attribute is causing it to do that.

Alternatively, is it possible to overwrite the [Authorize] Attribute and keep the originals functions after my conditions?

I get the BadRequest errors due to the way I am logging in as shown in this question: [.NET Core 2.2 Shared Cookie causes Bad Request error when logging in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58085203/net-core-2-2-shared-cookie-causes-bad-request-error-when-logging-in?noredirect=1#comment103094438_58085203)

EDIT: Added Custom Authorize Attribute

```
public class ExtendedAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext authorizationFilterContext)
    {
        if (authorizationFilterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
        {
            base.Function();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `Is it possible to set a breakpoint on the [Authorize] ?` 
  I'm afraid impossible
- `Is it possible to overwrite the [Authorize] Attribute and keep the originals functions after my conditions?` Yes, you can call the base class functions by using `base.Function()`

Comment: Hi Jimmy, is there a sample of the base.Function()? What is the type of base?

Comment: just use keyword `base` and chose function u want

Comment: Is there an example of overwriting the authorize attribute? I cant seem to find any. The ones i found asked to do it in Startup.cs instead of a class

Comment: I added my custom authorize attribute to my code. base.Function() does not exist though.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, in .net core, the Authorize attribute itself is not extensible. Maybe that will help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: The issue is that the Authorize attribute is causing my application to give out Bad Request errors that I cant put a breakpoint on.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a breakpoint inside the default [Authorize] filter, but you could debug the incoming request by providing your own `AuthenticateAsync` and inspect your request until you find out the problem.

The following snippet is from [Authentication Filters in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters).

```
public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // 1. Look for credentials in the request.
    HttpRequestMessage request = context.Request;
    AuthenticationHeaderValue authorization = request.Headers.Authorization;
```

Comment: Hi, where would I put this async?